# Is it acceptable to create an anonymous type query and then set that data to a SQL POCO class in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using C# with Entity framework asp.net MVC 4

Basically I want my index page to only have a few columns from my SQL table. But I still want to use that sql tables class.Here is my example for selecting only certain columns from SQL using Enity framework for a POCO class.

```
//in the controller I get back a list of student entities
var students = from s in studentRepository.GetStudents()
               select s;

//Below in the repository I have a function getstudents that with return all students
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
{

    //I create a list of anonymous types
    var result = (from a in context.Students
                  select new
                  {
                      FirstMidName = a.FirstMidName,
                  }
                 ).ToList();

    //I set the anonymous types to student types
    IEnumerable<Student> x = from k in result
                             select new Student
                             {
                                 FirstMidName = k.FirstMidName
                             };

     //I return the list of students with only there name variable set
     return x;
}
```

This is all the sql created

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Student'
```

So basically I was wondering is there anything wrong with my approach? Any problems that could occur for doing this. Also is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this DLL [**Value Injecter - convention based mapper**](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

The Value Injection is the algorithm that takes the values from the specific Properties (if it has properties, if it's an int/string etc. than just take the value) of the source object and inserts them into the properties of the target object. It chooses from which properties of the source object to take the values and where to put them in the source object.

[**Check documentation here**](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation)

```
 var result = (from a in context.Students
                  select new
                  {
                      FirstMidName = a.FirstMidName,
                  }
                      ).ToList();

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.InjectFrom(result);
```

Comment: Is this package supposed to improve performance or just shorten code? My goal is performance.

Comment: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ValueInjecter/LoopValueInjection.cs   Looking at the source it seems as a lot of extra work is being done. Seems like something more useful for a situation more complex than my index page. Thankyou for the help this maybe useful for future problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `.ToList`, you can use `.AsEnumerable` as well:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
{
    return context.Students
                .Select(s => new {s.FirstName})
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(s => new Student {FirstName=s.FirstName});
}
```

Also, I would recommend using LINQ method syntax in this case -- much more concise.